# WCF on an existing asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, wcf, webforms

i have an ASP.NET web forms that i want to start building an iPhone application for. and for that i think the best way is to expose y methods using WCF, and this my first time with WCF.

The project i currently have is a website created using: File > New > Website, not File > New > ASP.NET Web Forms project.

My questions are:

1. Can i use the code that i already have on my website, or i have to recreate the methods as WCF web methods.
2. Should i add WCF services to my current project or i have to create a new WCF project? if the second option how to deploy it ?

If there is a tutorial on how to do it, it would appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735119%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are new improvements to the ASP.NET framework.

You can expose your existing Web Forms functions using Web API.

[One ASP.NET - Making JSON Web APIs with ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta and ASP.NET Web API](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneASPNETMakingJSONWebAPIsWithASPNETMVC4BetaAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx)

[image]